# Stalk of motivic homotopy sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motivic-cohomology, motivic-homotopy, simplicial-presheaves

In contrast to "classical" homotopy theory, in the motivic homotopy theory, we don't have homotopy group but rather homotopy sheaves in the Nisnevich topology, which is associated to the presheaf
$$\pi_n^{\mathbb{A}^1}(\mathcal{X}):Sm_k\rightarrow \text{Ab},\quad U\mapsto [S^{i,j}\wedge U_+,\mathcal{X}]_{\mathbb{A}^1}.$$
Morphisms of spaces $\mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ induce morphisms of homotopy sheaves $\pi_n^{\mathbb{A}^1}(\mathcal{X})\rightarrow \pi_n^{\mathbb{A}^1}(\mathcal{Y})$. The Nisnevich topology has enough points,and thus an isomorphism of homotopy sheaves can be detected on stalks. So a natural question is what is the stalk of the homotopy sheaves? Is it enough to evalute $\pi_n^{\mathbb{A}^1}(\mathcal{X})$ on the spectra of local henselian rings?

Comment: Yes, sure.:) Moreover, in the motivic stable homotopy theory ($S^1$-stability is sufficient here; I don't know whether it is necessary) it suffices to evaluate homotopy groups at spectra of function fields.

Comment: @MikhailBondarko Would you happen to have a reference for this? Something I can quote?

Comment: Did you try Morel F., An introduction to A 1 -homotopy theory, in: Contemporary
Developments in Algebraic K-theory (M. Karoubi, A. O. Kuku, C. Pedrini
eds.), ICTP Lecture Notes, vol. 15, 2003, 357-441? It does not contain complete proofs, but the formulations are probably fine. Theorem 4.3.4 says something about the corresponding t-structure.:)